# In which joomla table is the global user configuration stored?

Tags: global-configuration

In my local joomla instance, in the global user configuration, I enabled the Allow User Registration option, also selected self option in New user account activation, among other options that include Enable Custom Fields in the Integration tab. Now I need to take a backup of these configurations but I don't know in which table or tables they are stored, this backup I plan to use it in another instance of the site.

In which joomla table is the global user configuration stored?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Component configuration is stored in `#__extensions` table.